# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400> in spring jersey controller

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

it's my controller...

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Path("/categories")
    public POSResponse getAllCategories() {
        String countryCode="1";
        return infoService.getAllCategories(countryCode);
    }
```

it's my testController....

```
  @Mock
    InfoService infoService;
    @InjectMocks
    private InfoController infoController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(infoController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllCategoriesTest() throws Exception {
        POSResponse response=new POSResponse();
        Category category=new Category();
        category.setCountryCode(1);
        category.setDescription("Mother Dairy");
        response.setResponse(category);

        when(infoService.getAllCategories("1")).thenReturn(response);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/categories"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.description", is("Mother Dairy")));

        verify(infoService, times(1)).getAllCategories("1");
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(infoService);
    }
```

i am using jersey controller. 
when i call the method i got error msg"java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>"

Comment: Are you sure that `infoService ` is injected into your controller? Looks to me, that you have to call `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` and then `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks `

Answer (score 1):

Whether you may use in your controller :

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // instead of MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED
```

Or, in you test :

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/categories")
       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE))
       ...
```

**Why?**

An HTTP request should be in one of the media types accepted by the server, and [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) might use [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON) (As my test show!). You can check it by printing the request detail:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/categories")
       .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED))
       .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
       ...
```